# Как исправить проблемку с git

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio, git-commit

```
You are using Git 0.0.0.0 which doesn't define %HOME% environment variable properly.
Consider updating Git to a newer version or define %HOME% to point to the place where the global .gitconfig is stored 
(it is usually %USERPROFILE% or %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%).
```

В android studio при коммите выскакивает эта ошибка. Что делать ?

Comment: Если в консоли выполнить `git --version`, что показывает?

Comment: git version 2.11.1.windows.1

Comment: Выглядит так, будто в Android Studio сбились настройки и она не находит путь к git. Попробуйте покопаться в настройках среды, в разделе VCS.

Comment: Ну и вы всегда можете через консоль работать ))

Comment: Я просто переносил проект с linux`а. Может как-то повлияло

Comment: А все. Ребутнул и заработало. Проблема исчерпана.

Comment: Всё хорошо, что хорошо кончается. Есть идеи, чем проблема была вызвана?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, так вы же сами хорошую версию выдвинули -- окружение слетевшее. При загрузке окружение пришло в значение по умолчанию.